# Red font in Firefox Page Source

Tags: html

I have been messing around with my meta descriptions, trying to make them more unique by showing relevant data from the database.

But when I check the meta description by right-clicking in Firefox and showing the page source, the meta description tags is in red color, making me think I have made some kind of mistake.

What does the red text usually mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 attributes are usually the most important one in meta tags: name and content

so description tag may look like

```
<meta name="description" content="My site description">
```

You probably forgot to close the double quotes, or using quotes-wrapper word in content attribute ?

```
<meta name="description" content="My "cool" site description">
```

in which case source viewer does not validate the code.

This is also valid for single quotes. If your meta tag uses single quotes and there's an apostrophe inside content attribute..

```
<meta name='description' content='Bob's website description'>
```

Comment: When I view source in Firefox, a particular whole of tag is in Red color. What does it means!?

Comment: Whole red colored tag means there is an error in that line. Normally it's just that reserved keywords are next to a " or '. There must be at least a space between them.

Answer (score 34):

If you hover over that red line, Firefox gives you the answer.

It may not be easy to intepret it, but it is precise enough.

Comment: in my case, it's nested-ish comments

Answer (score 9):

Red color in viewing source on Firefox indicates a syntax error, in the very basic structure of HTML tags. So it has nothing to do with the meaning of your tags or content, or even the names of tags and attributes.

To get a detailed error report, use a validator like http://validator.w3.org.

Comment: This is a pretty useful tool. Is there a Vs Code extension for this?

Answer (score 3):

Tag form cannot contain tag form

```
<form action="/">

.....

//RED FONT IN FIREFOX
<form action="/">
</form>


....
</form>
```