# Effects in menu

Tags: php, html, css

I have a problem I can not solve, I have two classes in php I call with include_once, then I show the content of the page that has effects on the menus, the problem is that when I call the two classes the effect of the page disappears and the menus are not visible, delete the contents of the classes and still the error persists, if I delete the page include_once going well.

index.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(1);

include_once("includes/Proveedores.php");
include_once("includes/Productos.php");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
      <meta content="initial-scale=1" name="viewport"><meta content="user-scalable=yes,width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport"><title>Administración</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/ico">
      <link href="css/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/more_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css">
      <script src="css/jquery-1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="header-wrapper">
         <div class="container">
            <header id="header">
               <div class="inner">
                  <h1 id="logo"><a href="#">Administración</a></h1>
                  <nav id="nav">
                     <ul>
                        <li style="white-space: nowrap;" class="current_page_item"><a href="http://localhost/tesis/administracion.php?">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li class="opener" style="-moz-user-select: none; cursor: pointer; white-space: nowrap;">
                           <a href="#">Cuenta</a>
                           <ul class="dropotron level-0" style="-moz-user-select: none; display: none; position: absolute; z-index: 1000;">
                              <li style="white-space: nowrap;"><a style="display: block;" href="http://localhost/tesis/administracion.php?editar_password">Cambiar contraseña</a></li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>                        
                        <li class="opener" style="-moz-user-select: none; cursor: pointer; white-space: nowrap;">
                           <a href="#">Gestionar</a>
                           <ul class="dropotron level-0" style="-moz-user-select: none; display: none; position: absolute; z-index: 1000;">
                              <li style="white-space: nowrap;"><a style="display: block;" href="http://localhost/tesis/administracion.php?clientes">Clientes</a></li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="http://localhost/tesis/administracion.php?calendario">Calendario</a></li>
                        <li style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="http://localhost/tesis/administracion.php?estadisticas">Estadísticas</a></li>
                        <li style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="http://localhost/tesis/administracion.php?logout">Salir</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </nav>
               </div>
               </header>              
            <br><br>
            <header class="major">
            </header>

            <center><h1><font color="white">Bienvenido a la administración</font></h1></center><br>

            <br>
            <header class="major">
            </header>

         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="12u">
            <div id="copyright">
               <ul class="menu">
                  <li>Creditos</li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Scripts -->
      <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery_002.js"></script>
      <script src="js/skel.js"></script>
      <script src="js/skel-viewport.js"></script>
      <script src="js/util.js"></script>
      <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
      <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body></html>
```

Proveedores

```
<?php

class Proveedor
{

}

?>
```

Productos

```
<?php
class Producto
{

}

?>
```

Classes have much code, delete its contents to see if the menu was walking but it was the same result.

Another thing that is not is that when using only one class, the menu if it works, but when I use the two will not run, also when the two classes use a blank line on page is added.

Note : The effect menu is a drop-down menu

What is the problem ?

Comment: Try looking at the page source for errors

Comment: when I add the two classes, these lines turn red in firefox source code: <! DOCTYPE html>
<html> <head>
</ head>
<body>

Comment: I don't know what "turn red in firefox source code" means. Push Ctrl-U to view the source code.

Comment: those lines in the source code are red

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain myself. I know what it means, but I don't know what it implies.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850931/red-font-in-firefox-page-source

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem. You can't have anything - blank spaces, new lines - before the `DOCTYPE` tag.

You can do this to fix it:

```
<?php

error_reporting(1);

include_once("includes/Proveedores.php");
include_once("includes/Productos.php");

?><!DOCTYPE html>
```

or call the `<?php` part after the `DOCTYPE` tag, which is more secure to work, since there can be extra whitespaces in the included PHP files.

Comment: The line break following the `?>` tag does NOT output a line break to the page.

Comment: Then add the PHP tag after `DOCTYPE`

Comment: change the location of the code php and the effect returned, but always where I put the includes , add a new line blank in the page